# Cassandra partion Key

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cql

Currently, I am exploring cassandra and having an special use case to design an support view of an application

My access patterns.

To fetch specific transaction

```
select * from purchase_by_user where userid='Tom' and transaction_date='1/20/22'
select * from purchase_by_user where userid='Jerry' and transaction_date <=1/21/22 and transaction_date >= '1/16/22'
select * from purchase_by_user where userid='Tom' and amount="100"
select * from purchase by user where user='Jerry' and amount>='50'

Create table purchase_by_user (
   order_id uuid,
   amount decimal,
   transaction_ts timestamp,
   user_id text,
   Primary key((user_id), uuid)
)
```

Lets say Tom is making millions of orders, With this above partion key the data will not be evenly spread against the cluster and also the search will be expensive here.

Can anyone help, what would be better partion key here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a `PRIMARY KEY` definition like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY((user_id, transaction_year), transaction_date, order_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_date DESC, order_id ASC)
```

This makes use of the "bucketing" concept that Manish mentioned.  In this case, if Tom is creating an order every single day, there will only be 365 in each partition.

> Lets say Tom is making millions of orders

In fact, even if Tom placed *two* orders per day, it's still only be 730.  So while thinking about throughput extremes is a good exercise, a single user placing even one million orders is probably not realistic.

Also, some of the queries above are using `transaction_date` in a range query.  I've added `transaction_date` as the first clustering key to support those queries.  And if `transaction_date` is in `DESC`ending order, the most-recent transactions will be at the "top" of the partition (they'll be read first), which is usually how most date/time-driven applications tend to function.

Comment: Thank you , Consider there could be order  thousands in a day, (eg: 60k in a month). If we want to perform a search based on transaction_ts or amount. How effective the search will be based on the partition key. Can it perform well during search. select * from purchase_by_user where user_id='tom' and  transaction_year>2021 and  amount="100.00"

Comment: select * from purchase_by_user where user_id='tom' and transaction_year>2021 and amount>="100.00" and amount<="500"

Comment: @Imran Typically, you would need to build a new table for every query you want to support.  However, as long as you're using an equals operator (not a > or <) on _all_ partition keys, you could get away with a secondary index on `amount`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of bucketing to reduce the number of rows in a single partition. For example you can create a key like (user_id int, bucket_number int). Here you can identify the max value of bucket_number on your expected data size. IF you expect this user can make millions order then you can have bucket value till 1000. The main idea is to focus that you dont end up creating partition with large number of rows.